# Installing Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

I was trying to install Rails Gem from the Command prompt. And my PC just Switched off.

Now when i try to install it again. i get the following problem

I am on Windows 7

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
gem update
gem install rails
```

Comment: I'm a newbie too.haha,I think some dependent not support the version of the rails

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you were aware of [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) which has all the common packages needed for a full Rails stack.

Answer (score 1):

On Win 7, follow steps and you will good to go

**First** you need to install RubyInstaller from below link

http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

**after that** install **Development Kit** from the below link refere document

Document - https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit

Download - http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

**Download rubygems** from below link

http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.8.17.zip

extract and execute ruby setup.rb (more informations - http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3)

after that **install rails** - gem install rails

Comment: what is the Development Kit for ?

Comment: For Windows, some native C/C++ extensions doesn't enables by ruby installer, so this kit build many of the native C/C++ extensions available for Ruby.